# Java assigning a new value to a parameter, is this considered a bad practice?

Tags: java, parameters, variable-assignment

I have read the question here: [Is it problematic to assign a new value to a method parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229389/is-it-problematic-to-assign-a-new-value-to-a-method-parameter). However it is not clear to me if doing something like:

```
public void myMethod(Object obj) {
    doSomething(obj);
    obj = getNewObj();
}
```

or:

```
public void anotherMethod(Object obj) {
     obj = doSomething(obj):
}
```

This is basically just to avoid declaring a new local variable, is this worth it?, is this seen as a bad practice?.

Comment: I think you understand this, but to be sure: in your two example methods the assignment to `obj` is accomplishing nothing at all since the new object isn't used afterwards in the method.

Comment: Yes I know this, but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bad practice.  You will be hard pressed to find a scenario where the sacrificed readability is worth it.  This will be especially confusing to anyone who doesn't understand Java's "pass by value" policy, which sadly is a lot of people.

Comment: A "lot of people" sampled from which population? I think this depends a lot on the context. What matters is the level of competence of those who will inherit my code. When writing code in a professional setting, I think it reasonable to assume my successors know how method parameters are passed. In contrast, I would not assume that when posting code as part of a tutorial on - say - a game programming website.

Comment: @meriton, I find it true of programmers who may be very experienced professionally, but new to Java and coming from a backgroud of a pass-by-reference language (at least where it was an option).

Comment: @meriton I work for a large corporation and have come across plenty of professional java developers who don't understand this concept. I'm not trying to condone it, but at a lot of companies its a reality.

Comment: @meriton I do agree with you that its fair to assume your successor will understand basic java concepts, but I just don't see the payoff in this particular case.