# Is it a bad practice to use arrays as parameter(s) to return multiple values

Tags: java

I sometimes (actually, often) find myself using a one-element array to return multiple values from a method. Something like this:

```
public static int foo(int param1, int param2[], String param3[])
{
    // method body
    ....
    // set return values
    param2[0] = <some value>;
    param3[0] = <some value>;

    return <some value>;
}
```

Is this a bad practice? (It seems like it is because some of my friends said they didn't know what it was doing for 2 seconds!)
But the reason I used this in the first place was because this looked closest to what is know as `pass-by-reference` in C++. And the practice wasn't discouraged in `C++`, so ...

But if this is really a wrong way of doing things, any idea how to rewrite this in the clean way?

Thanks

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code - you are assigning `some value` to `param2[0]` twice. If that **really** is what you're doing, then I don't have a clue how it works...

Comment: Objects are made for that: encapsulate several fields which have a meaning,  coherence

Comment: <some value> simply means 'some value'. It is a gramatical description. Surely doesn't indicate two of its occurrences should have the same "value"

Comment: There are many better ways to _simulate_ pass by reference in Java.

Comment: @jahroy What are the better ways that you were mentioning? Could you give a few examples? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not wrong.  May not be the best approach in all circumstances, but can easily be the best approach in a given set of circumstances.  Defining a new object just to pass parameters is a really ugly solution -- it clutters the code, clutters the name space.

Comment: @jahroy - How are those better?

Comment: Well... maybe they aren't.  Do you have a suggestion about what the OP should do?  Are you saying that his approach is sound?  I would argue that it's not possible to tell based on the limited info he's shared.

Comment: I'm saying (again) that the approach is not "wrong", given the constraints of Java.  Is it elegant?  No.  But elegance in real (vs academic) programming is overrated.

Comment: @HotLicks - Cool.  I'm not arguing with you... You are correct that this approach is not  _technically_ wrong.  I guess I was just trying to suggest a possible alternative to what seems like a suspicious approach (even tho we don't know exactly what the real code looks like).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with the general opinion here that using arrays for such a purpose is bad practice, I'd like to add a few things.
Are you sure that "pass by reference" really is what you need in the first place? 
Many have said that your code is bad style, but now let me tell you why that is IMHO.
"Pass by reference" is mostly a synonym for "programming by side effect" which is a thing you always want to avoid. It makes code much harder to debug and understand, and in a multi-threaded environment, the bad effects of this attitude really can hit you hard.
To write scalable and thread-safe code in Java, you should make objects "read-only" as much as possible, i.e. ideally, you create an object and initialize it at the same time, then use it with this unmodifiable state throughout your application. Logical changes to the state can almost always be considered a "creation" of new state, i.e. creation of a new instance initialized to a state then needed. Many modern scripting languages only let you work in this way, and it makes things much easier to understand.
As opposed to C++, Java is much more efficient in allocating and releasing short-lived objects, so there is actually nothing wrong with what others here have suggested: To create an instance of a special class to hold the function result, just for the purpose of returning the result. Even if you do that in a loop, the JVM will be smart enough to deal with that efficiently. Java will only allocate memory from the OS in very large chunks when needed, and will deal with object creation and release internally without the overhead involved in languages like C/C++. "Pass by reference" really doesn't help you very much in Java.

EDIT: I suggest you search this forum or the net for the terms "side-effect", "functional programming" or "immutability". This will most likely open a new perspective to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer.

Comment: If Java is that efficient with small object allocation why then Doug Lea uses pass by reference here java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicStampedReference#get(int[] stampHolder)?

Comment: I think this example is a very special use case. AtomicStampedReference, as the name implies, represents a reference to an instance, so it would have been inconsistent for the "get()" method to return something other than the referenced instance. The author of that class then chose to make the "stamp" associated with the instance available by side-effect, so the "get" method can still return the instance itself, not some return value object, because this is what you would expect of a "get" method on a class named "...Reference". I doubt that he decided to to this for performance reasons.

Comment: Object creation of course creates *some* overhead, but it just isn't as significant as in C/C++, because "new" or "malloc" effectively are system calls, and system calls are always a huge performance hit, mostly because of the kernel/user space transition. Java only calls "malloc" rarely, to get large chunks of memory, while all Java heap operations are handled internally. It really makes much more sense to worry about maintainability and readability of your code than to try to optimize performance when in most cases it really wouldn't make your code run any faster.

Comment: Isn't the JVM implemented in C/C++? Whatever you do to efficiently manage the memory in Java can be done in C/C++. The JVM is a program implemented in C/C++. But that is not the point here. Why the creators of the Java libraries want you to pass an array instead of returning a new object? I agree that it is a bad practice but yet the not-so-old concurrent API does exactly that. Why?

Comment: [move this down] But these APIs go through lots of reviews by everybody involved with the design of the language. It is definitely ugly and confusing. They could have changed the name to something else if "get" was the problem. Performance is the only reasonable explanation.

Comment: Of course you can theoretically do more in C/C++ than you can do in Java. But many man-years of work have gone into the implementation of Java's memory management and garbage collection, and it is just crazy to do that in a business app when there is something like Java. Java is a general-purpose language, though, and so in the API there are concepts that allow for *potentially* faster code, if used correctly. Your example from the concurrent API is not the only one, just think of "System.arrayCopy". I just think this isn't something you should normally worry about when doing a business app.

Answer (score 6):

Create an object that contains the data you want to return.

Then you can return an instance of that object.

```
class FooData {
    private int someInt;
    private int anotherInt;
    private String someString;

    public FooData(int a, int b, String c) {
        someInt = a;
        anotherInt = b;
        someString = c;
    }
}

public FooData foo() {
    // do stuff
    FooData fd = new FooData(blah, blahh, blahhh);
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: If you were to call `foo()` in a loop, you would end up creating multiple `FooData`objects, yeah? I thought the use of array was just the Java's way of doing what is called `pass-by-reference` in C++.

Comment: Yes, multiple FooData objects would be created if this method was called multiple times.  I see no problem with that.  If you wanted to (I see no reason) you could instantiate a single FooData object and pass that to the method for re-use.  I see no reason to do this, but you could.

Comment: There are many good reasons to use arrays.  You are abusing them as a workaround for your poor design.

Comment: Erm, memory allocation expense?

Comment: @user1508893 - If you're really concerned about memory usage, you can just instantiate a single `FooData` object and pass that to your method.  That way you only use one FooData instance. That being said, I see no reason to do this.

Comment: Except that creating an "object" to return your data is not different from creating an array.  An array is an object.  (And one that doesn't clutter the name space like a new parameter object would.)

Comment: @HotLicks - The OP isn't creating an array.  He's passing in several arrays just so he can have his method manipulate/return multiple values.  The only reason he is using arrays is because he can modify their values.

Comment: So?  Why would you be using your object?  Would it be there if you didn't need to modify the parms?  In his case he can have the arrays appropriately named on both sides, so that no meaning is lost, even if in one use a parm is the Pope's age and another use the same parm is the age of the universe.

Comment: @HotLicks -  I really know nothing about how the OP's code works. I would probably call three separate methods to get 3 separate results. If I wanted three results to come from one method, I would probably create an object to hold the results and return it from my method. I only suggested the second approach (that I would not use) because the OP expressed a concern about allocating new objects. I would not have that concern in most situations.  One thing I would **NOT** do is pass an array as a parameter _just_ so it can modify the value of a _single_ int value.

Comment: I'm removing the second half of my answer... I only added it as a response to the OP's comments.  It's an approach that I would never use and should have never suggested.

Comment: Yet you would define a new class, create an instance of it, and pass it.  I fail to see the distinction.

Comment: @HotLicks - No, I would **return** the instance of the object.  I would not pass it to the method as a parameter... That's the part of my answer that I've been trying to retract for a couple hours.  I never would've taken that approach, but mentioned it to the OP in response to his comment.  I wish I never mentioned it...

Answer (score 4):

I believe that it is bad practice to "return" values using one-element arrays that are parameters to your method.

Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970984/java-assigning-a-new-value-to-a-parameter-is-this-considered-a-bad-practice) about this topic.  In short, it's very bad for readability.

There is an easy workaround: Wrap all values that you wish to return in a class you define specifically for this purpose, and return an instance of that class.

```
return new ValueHolder(someValue1, someValue2, someValue3);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not very idiomatic java. There are usually better approaches to software design.

What you're really doing with the "one-element array" is creating a mutable object (since String is immutable, as are primitives like int) and passing it by reference. Modifying this mutable object is called a "side effect" of the method. In general, you should minimize mutability ([Effective Java Item 15](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA76&ots=yYIfOfr6OX&dq=effective%20java%20immutable&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20immutable&f=false)) and your methods should be side-effect free. There are a couple approaches here.

#### 1. Split the method into two (or three) methods that all take the same params:

```
public static int foo1(int param1)
{
    // method body
    ....
    return <some value>;
}
```

Similarly, you might have

`public static int foo2(int param1) { ... }`

and

`public static String foo3(int param1) { ... }`.

#### 2. Return a composite object.

```
public Container {
    private final int originalReturn;
    private final int param2;
    private final String param3;

    public Container(int originalReturn, int param2, String param3) {
        this.originalReturn = originalReturn;
        this.param2 = param2;
        this.param3 = param3;
    }

    // getters
}

public static Container foo(int param1, int param2[], String param3[])
{
    // method body
    ....
    // set return values
    return new Container(<some value>, <some value>, <some value>);
}
```

Comment: So you down voted because I included a reference rather than just stating my opinion?

Comment: *If* I down-voted, it was because you're employing cookbook programming.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed bad practice if the values are unrelated. This is usually an indicator that you can split that function into two, with each returning one of the values.

EDIT:

I am assuming that you are returning two values calculated in the method in an array. Is this not the case?

e.g.

```
public int[] getStatistics(int[] nums)
{
    //code

    int[] returns = new int[2];
    returns[0] = mean;
    returns[1] = mode;

    return returns;
}
```

The above function could be split into `getMean()` and `getMode()`.

Comment: I prefer public int[] getStatistics(int[] nums, int[] out ){ ... if( out == null ) out = new ...; ... return out; } because the client has the choice to instantiate itself the array possibly once when it call getStatistics many times

Comment: @Aubin I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The comment you don't understand has nothing to do with the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Passing variables by reference allows the function to "legally" change their value. See [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html) to clear up the confusion of when this is possible in Java, and when it's not...

Comment: Java never passes "variables" by reference.  That, indeed, is the problem the OP is trying to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad practice if the values are of different type and different entities, e.g. name and address, etc. It is fine with create an array with same data type, e.g list of addresses.