# Java: Meaning of catch (final SomeException e) ? Is Final Keyword makes any sense here?

Tags: java, exception, final

Here is Some Code written by some of my Senior team member.

```
  private void getYourObjectByID(final long someId) {
            TypedQuery<LoanBusinessIndustry> v_objQuery;
            try {
                //Some Code JPA Read Write To Database 
            } catch (final Exception ex) {  //is final here makes any sense ?
                System.err.println("exception get at query getLoanBusinessIndustry=>" + ex.getMessage());
                this.logger.error("No Data found for getLoanBusinessIndustry=>" + ex.toString());
            }
        }
```

In Parameter of Method `getYourObjectByID(final long someId)` making Id as a Final make sense. `someId` Value should not change because `Data Objects` are fetched from `db` according to `someId` But........

```
 //Complete Catch Block Implemented Code.
catch (final Exception ex) {  //is final here makes any sense ?
       System.err.println("exception get at query =>" + ex.getMessage());
       this.logger.error("No Data found for =>" + ex.toString());
                }
```

In `catch()` Block making `Exception` Class Object `ex` as `final`. Is it really make sense because we are handling this exception with in this `Catch` Block Itself not trying to `Rethrow`.

> Question: Does Final Keyword used in `catch` make any Sense or not ?????

Comment: take a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516816/java-meaning-of-catch-final-someexception-e

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `final` keyword simply makes explicit the fact that the `variable` is implicitly final. The [Java Language Specification states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) (emphasis my own):

> A resource of a try-with-resources statement (§14.20.3) and an exception parameter of a multi-catch clause (§14.20) are **implicitly declared final**.

Comment: I know that ..  Actually i have handled this `exception` in catch block itself okk  so ,i just want to know is any purpose of doing that?  @austin

Comment: But this isn't a multi-catch clause. Without the `final`, you'd be able to assign `ex = null`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks! I tried to capture your example in my migrated answer (see link below)

@VikrantKashyap My answer applies to *multi-catch caluses*. I moved it to http://stackoverflow.com/a/35915520/3795219
and expanded it to directly address your issue with `final` in a *uni-catch clause*. Let me know when you see this, I'm going to delete this answer.