# How to avoid too many null comparisons

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jena

I am working with `JENA framework` to scrape info about public contracts and publish it as RDF and I can't get over following problem:
When creating new RDF model, I create new `Resource` for each contract and then assign bunch of properties (that I scraped) using JENA's `addProperty(Property, RDFNode)` or `addProperty(Property, String)` method. The problem is, that some contracts are missing some properties so I get `NullPointerException`.
Using

```
if(contract.getProperty() != null)
{
   resource.addProperty(VOCABULARY.property, contract.getProperty());
}
```

for every single property is probably not the best way and since the second parameter of `addProperty()` method differs a lot
(it can be directly the `contract.getProperty()`, but sometimes also `model.createLiteral(contract.getProperty())` or
`model.createTypedLiteral(contract.getProperty(), XSDDataType.XSDInt)` and so on), I can't create my own `myAddProperty()` method
where I would check for `null` and call JENA's `addProperty()`.
What would you suggest as a best solution to skip all the null properties?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: What type of class is the resource variable? Can you inherit from that class and override the `addProperty()` method?

Comment: Why can't a "myAddProperty()" that then calls the "addProperty()" method?

Comment: @Marcelo the resource variable is com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource type, good idea, I'll try to ingerit and override addProperty()

Comment: I am curious, why can't you add a little myAddProperty method, either private in your class, or as a static method in a helper class?

Comment: @Peter and JustinKSU you guys are probably right, I was stupid, by saying I can't create it, I meant there is so many different parameters you can pass to original `addProperty()`, but actually all the `model.createTypedLiteral()` stuff and so on returns Strings, so I CAN do it. Thanks, I was stupid, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the null check into a separate method:

```
private void addProperty(final Resource resource, final String key, final String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        resource.addProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

You can then use this method as follows:

```
addProperty(resource, VOCABULARY.property, contract.getProperty());
```

Comment: one question, why to use `final` parameters?

Comment: @tom - This is apparently quite a controversial practice! See the debate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500508/why-should-i-use-the-keyword-final-on-a-method-parameter-in-java Personally, I think it increases the readability (and intent) of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with those frameworks but maybe you can subclass `Resource` and do something like this? :

```
@overrides
public void addProperty(String key, String value)
{
   if (value != null) super.addProperty(key,value);
}
```

Comment: well, com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource is actually an interface

Comment: oh, sorry. Is the implementation of that interface something you can intercept at least (like an aspect for example)?

Comment: the interface has a lot of methods, so it's pretty long, I think I can just create `myAddProperty()` actually (as discussed above), but thanks for your idea, it really helped me a lot