# Need help diagnosing a NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am new to generics and I am trying out to make a linked list.

Here is the Code for Node_ class.

```
public class Node_<T> {

    private int index;
    private T data;
    private Node_<T> next;
    public Node_() {
    }

    public Node_(T data, int index) {
        this.data = data;
        this.index = index;
        next = null;
    }

    public void set(T data, int index) {
        this.data = data;
        this.index = index;
        this.next= null;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(this.data.toString());
    }

    public void setindex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node_<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next != null) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }
}
```

and linked list class.

```
public class LinkList<T> {    
    private int total = 0;
    private Node_<T> start;
    private Node_<T> end;
    private Node_<T> ptr;

    public LinkList() {
    }    

    public LinkList(T data) {
        start = new Node_<T>(data, 0);
        end = start;
        ptr = start;
        total++;
    }

    public void add(T data) {
        if (start == null) {
            start = new Node_<T>(data, 0);
            end = start;
            ptr = start;
            total++;
        } else {
            end.set((T) data,(int) total);
            total++;
            end = end.getNext();
        }
    }


    public void displayAt(int index) {
        if (start != null) {
            ptr = start;
            do {
                if (ptr.getIndex() == index)
                    ptr.display();
            } while (ptr.hasNext());
        }

        else
            System.out.println("No Element found");
    }

    public void displayAll() {
        if (start != null) {
            ptr = start;
            do {
                ptr.display();
            } while (ptr.hasNext());
        }

        else
            System.out.println("No Element Present");
    }
}
```

The following code in Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        LinkList<Integer> list = new LinkList<Integer>(25);
        list.displayAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            list.add((Integer) i);
        }
        list.displayAll();
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error and i cant figure out the problem.

```
25
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LinkList.add(LinkList.java:26)
at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Any suggestion where am I going wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: Use an IDE and step through your code.

Comment: @user3426273 Stack trace indicates that something on the left side of a `.` is `null` in `LinkList.add()`. Looking at the code (and guessing since you did not mark the indicated lines in the snippet) the only thing that could satisfy those conditions is if `end` is `null`. So, find out why and fix that.

Comment: @KevinBowersox `end.set(...)` would be the source if `end` were `null`, as it happens first.

Comment: LinkList.add(LinkList.java:26) read line 26.

Comment: @JasonC this source file may have two extra lines if it has a package declaration and a extra blank line.

Comment: @Mauren I don't understand why you are telling me this, sorry.

Comment: `Node_` and `LinkList` both have constructors that leave fields null. You might start by fixing that.

Comment: @JasonC your prev comment answering Kevin Bowersox.

Comment: @Mauren Thanks for clarifying. No it was unrelated to line numbers (we don't actually know what the line numbers are). If you follow the code and presume `end` is `null`, it *must* throw the NPE on the `end.set(...)` line. It could not get to `end.getNext()` as `end.set(...)` would throw first. It's not really an issue of the specific line numbers.

Comment: @JasonC yes, it was what I diagnosed as well. After counting lines I just presumed line number was wrong, because of this assumption: if `end` is `null` the NPE would be thrown two lines prior.

Comment: @JasonC You are right it is on that line during the second iteration.  Since end is assigned to the return value of `getNext` which is null during the first iteration.

Comment: @KevinBowersox that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Mauren I'm so thankful for debuggers!

Answer (score 3):

### Cause of `NullPointerException`

The method `Node_.set()` leaves the value of `end.next` null. This means that the after you've been around the loop once you get a NullPointerException.

### Corrected `add(Node_<T>)` method

It appears that rather than adding a new node to the list you are setting the contents of the last node. I think you should be constructing a new node, setting `end.next` to point to this new node and, finally, setting `end` as the new node.

```
public void add(final T data) {
    if (start == null) {
        start = new Node_<T>(data, 0);
        end = start;
        ptr = start;
        total++;
    } else {
        end.setNext(new Node_<T>(data, total));
        total++;
        end = end.getNext();
    }
}
```

It should be noted that you'll need to update the Node_ class to provide a setter for the `next` variable - at the moment it is initialised to `null` and cannot be changed.

### Fix for `displayAll()` method

And finally, once you do create a LinkedList your `displayAll` routine next moves along the list, if there are multiple elements it just prints the first element forever. You need to include a `ptr = ptr.getNext()`. Something like this works:

```
public void displayAll() {
    if (start != null) {
        ptr = start;
        while (ptr != null) {
            ptr.display();
            ptr = ptr.getNext();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No Element Present");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
I am such a stupid.

Comment: I cant figure out why final is used in add method's parameter

Comment: It's readability / code style thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500508/why-should-i-use-the-keyword-final-on-a-method-parameter-in-java.

Answer (score 0):

When the `LinkedList` is instantiated it creates a new `Node` and assigns it to `start`, `end` and `ptr`.  When the new `Node` is created `next` is assigned null:

```
public Node_(T data, int index) {
    this.data = data;
    this.index = index;
    next = null; //assigned null
}
```

The `add` method is then called repeatedly within the body of the loop.  During the first iteration, `end` is assigned the return value of `getNext` which is null.  On the second iteration a method on `end` is invoked causing a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

```
public void add(T data) {
    if (start == null) {
        start = new Node_<T>(data, 0);
        end = start;
        ptr = start;
        total++;
    } else {
        end.set((T) data,(int) total); //end is null on second iteration
        total++;
        end = end.getNext(); //Set to null on the first iteration
    }
}
```