# Arraylist and List with Final keyword

Tags: java, arraylist, final

Which advantages/disadvantages of making `ArrayList` (or other Collection) final? And what if we try to do so like:

```
final List<Integer> A=new ArrayList<Integer>(1,2,3,4,5);
List<Integer> l=new ArrayList<Integer>(4,8,16);
A=l;
```

Is this is valid?
Now the reference A will point to this Array list pointed by l?  Please help.

Comment: 1) `final` *affects the variable*, and not the object to which is refers. 2) It is not *not allowed* to re-assign to a `final` variable. The compiler should have said as much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380512/2864740 (this answer is more generalized than the question) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012 (specific to final fields, discusses object mutability as well)

Comment: Also, `ArrayList` does not have a constructor that will allow that usage.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

No, reassignment to final reference is not allowed in Java.