# Why we do mark method’s parameters as final while using Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch

I started learning Elasticsearch recently, have watched already a couple of videos about this technology and noticed that we mark fields in the method’s parameters as *final*. Simultaneously, we don’t mark parameters with this keyword when use MySQL, for the instance.

Why? Because there are no field locks and transactions inside of Elasticsearch unlike MySQL?

For example:

Let’s suppose that we have a REST controller for users in our app and a method that return user based on its id inside of this controller.

In the case when we use MySQL:

```
@GetMapping(“/user/{id}”)
public User getUserById(@ParhVariable Long id) {
return userRepository.getById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

In the case when we use Elasticsearch:

```
@GetMapping(“/user/{id}”)
public User getUserById(@ParhVariable final Long id) {
return userRepository.getById(id).orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: do you know what the final keyword does when applied to a variable?

Comment: @Stultiske of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not connected to ElasticSearch or MySQL. When you set `final` keyword to your `id` variable - you just can't assign a new value (an object in case of `Long`) to this variable inside your `getUserById` method.

It prevents such situations:

```
@GetMapping(“/user/{id}”)
public User getUserById(@ParhVariable Long id) {
    id = 10L; // new value
    return userRepository.getById(id).orElse(null); // will response with wrong entity
}
```

In code above the program will NOT return the value, which user expected. And if you set `final` keyword on `id` variable and try to assign new value to `id` - the program will not even compile, which prevents not expected behavior in runtime.

There is no strict rules always to use `final` or not - the most common approach is to use `final` when code is long and complicated.

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380512/13991201) answer.